# How to implement a count in a subquery

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following table structures:

```
TABLE A:
ID
COL1
COL2
...
COL(n)

TABLE B:
ID
A_ID (id in table A)
VALUE
```

There is a one-to-many relationship from A->B

```
class A {
    int id
    ...
    coln
    Set<String> bSet

    static hasMany = [bSet: B]

    static mapping = {
        restrictions joinTable: [name: "B", key: "A_ID", column: "VALUE"]
    }
}
```

How can I build a criteria so that it executes a query such as follows:

```
select table1.* from A table1 where (select count(*) from B table2 where table2.A_ID = table1.ID and table2.VALUE in ('excluded_value_1','excluded_value_2')) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, obviously untested but might give you something to start from

```
def a = A.createCriteria()
a.list {
 createAlias("bSet", "b", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
 not {
    'in'("b",['excluded_value_1','excluded_value_2'])
 }
}
```